# Truncated text behaving differently in Mozilla

Tags: html, css, mozilla

I have a container that has a string text (which could be very long) and a floating inline element as depicted [here](https://jsfiddle.net/gzjf2psq/).

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <span>RIGHT</span>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa.
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
span {
  float: right;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-color: #26a69a;
  padding: 0 6px;
}

.container {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

In case the string text is long it gets truncated and this works fine in chrome. Running it on mozilla, on the other hand, displays the truncated text behind(in front) of the floated inline object. Could someone please explain to me why this is so and how to correct it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you are providing `text-overflow: ellipsis`, you need to apply fix width to the container stating the browser to make it `ellipsis` after that fixed width.

Chrome generally inherits the fix width of the parent or container and applies the properties. However, you need to manually mention it in Firefox.

For `ellipsis`, its also better if you change the structure to have the text content inside a `span` or a `div`.

Check updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gzjf2psq/1/).

Refer code:

```css
span {
  float: right;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-color: #26a69a;
  padding: 0 6px;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 540px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span>RIGHT</span>
  <div class="wrapper">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks this works for me and thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```css
 body{
        float: left;
        margin: 0;
        max-width: 100%;
    }
.container {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-right: 80px;
    position: relative;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width:100%;
   
}

span {
    background-color: #26a69a;
    border-radius: 2px;
    display: block;
    float: right;
    padding: 0 6px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<span>RIGHT</span>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa.
</div>
```

JS Fiddle demo : https://jsfiddle.net/geogeorge/gzjf2psq/6/

Comment: this seems to add a horizontal scroll bar and not ellipsis as I expected.